# Unity WWW Text response is garbled

Tags: web, text, unity-game-engine, httprequest

I am using the sample code from the Unity website for the WWW class to make an API request but the text response is garbage. It looks like ����. When I log the response headers, I get a 200 response and everything seems ok except that the CONTENT-TYPE is image/jpeg. I have tried several different random .json files to test it out and they all return the same thing. Requesting an image to use as a texture does work.

```
public class SpeechReq : MonoBehaviour {
//public string url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wethecode/1f79baf168680afb0f2d/raw/755f9fb71dcc34df811b4bc26448d88a0f97f34d/snippets.json";
public string url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/damienh/fea91ab710475d499a09/raw/893065428badd8bfdc7b39fe17675b8aa031ac51/gistfile1.json";
IEnumerator Start()
{
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;

    string respText = www.text;
    Debug.Log(respText);
    //Output: ����

    byte[] resp = www.bytes;
    var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(resp);
    Debug.Log(str);
    //Output: ÿØÿà

    if (www.responseHeaders.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in www.responseHeaders)
        {
            Debug.Log(entry.Value + "=" + entry.Key);
            //Output: HTTP/1.0 200 OK=STATUS
            //...
            //image/jpeg=CONTENT-TYPE
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The WWW class's .text method returns the UTF8 Byte Order Mark at the beginning of the response by default. See [a description of the BOM here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

You could try:

```
 string jsonText = "";
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error)) 
 {
     jsonText = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(www.bytes, 3, www.bytes.Length - 3);  // Skip the UTF8 BOM
     JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(jsonText);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks but all that seems to be doing is eliminating the �. I now get one instead of 4 but it's not actually parsing the text. If I skip the first 4 bytes it's just an empty response. Output in console is: improper JSON formatting:�

Comment: @willjfield use something like Wireshark or Fiddler to see precisely what's coming back... I can see that link if I paste it into the browser but it is coming back as text/plain rather than application/json.